# SQL SUM and nested where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sum, where-clause

I have an SQL that takes an id, a start date and an end date  as parameters.  I then sum certain that are restricted by the where clause.  However I need to also sum the same column that doesnt take into account the data params and calculates the total for a particular driver.  For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
PMTS.VolunteerId,
PMTS.ChargeRate,
SUM(
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 418 THEN Amount
  ELSE 0
END
) AS DriverMileage,
SUM(
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 1000 THEN Amount
  ELSE 0
END
) AS GPMileage,
SUM(
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 1001 THEN Amount
  ELSE 0
END
) AS Reimbursements,
SUM(
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 1002 THEN Amount
  ELSE 0
END
) AS MobilePhoneCharges,
SUM(Mileage) AS TotalMileageWeek,
B.TotalMileage,
VOLS.Address1,
VOLS.Address2,
VOLS.Town,
ISNULL(VOLS.Surname, '') + ', ' + ISNULL(VOLS.Forename, '') AS SurnameForename ,
ISNULL(VOLS.County, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(VOLS.PostCode, '') AS CountyPostcode 
FROM dbo.vVolunteerPayments PMTS
INNER JOIN dbo.vVolunteers VOLS ON PMTS.VolunteerId = VOLS.VolunteerID
--total mileage
INNER JOIN (select VolunteerId, sum(Mileage) as TotalMileage 
      FROM dbo.vVolunteerPayments GROUP BY VolunteerId) b ON 
b.VolunteerID=PMTS.VolunteerId
WHERE 
PMTS.VolunteerId = @volunteerid 
AND 
PMTS.PaymentEventID = 0
AND
PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed
GROUP BY 
PMTS.VolunteerId
,Address1
,Address2
,Town
,County
,PostCode
,Surname
,Forename
,B.TotalMileage
,PMTS.ChargeRate
```

So the SUM(Mileage) As MileageTotal ignores the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate the `where` clause and do conditional summation:

```
Select Name,
       SUM(case when Journey.DateCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate then Mileage
                else 0
           end) As MileageWeek,
       SUM(Mileage) As MileageTotal
from Journey
```

I also added back in the `from` clause (presumably you left it out accidentally).

```
SUM(
CASE [Type]
  WHEN 418 THEN Amount
  ELSE 0
END
) AS DriverMileage,
```

to

```
sum(case when [type] = 418 and PMTS.DateCreated BETWEEN @sd AND @ed then amount
         else 0
    end) as DriverMileage
```

You may need to include more conditionals from the `where` clause -- I'm not sure which total you want.

Comment: I might need to do it like that in the end as I can only have one recordset returned otherwise the report control generates a new page

Comment: I've updated the query to show the full text - any suggestions Cheers

Comment: Cheers Gordon - thats the one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  Select 
    a.Name,
    SUM(Mileage) As MileageWeek,
    SUM(Mileage) As MileageTotal,
    b.TotMiles
    FROM <table> a
    JOIN (select name,sum(Mileage) as TotMiles 
          FROM <table> GROUP By name) b ON b.name=a.name
    WHERE
    Journey.DateCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

Replace `< table >` with your actual table name (**Journey**???)

Comment: I thought this might have been the answer but it returns two record sets.  I need a singular record set return for the report.  I tied the solution below but this returns multiple recordsets again and

Comment: I've updated the query to show the full text - any suggestions  Cheers